# Delete object or set to null

Tags: javascript, jquery, recursion

[My Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UnWsJ/5/)

Nothing appears on the screen it's all in the console.

The Rundown:
So this is for a project I'm working on. Basically I'm trying to deconstruct the giant object at the top of my script into smaller objects that contain all the required data (wholeObject in the code). So that I can reconstruct them in the next step of this project.

Right now this is producing an infinite loop, but what I'm trying to do here is get to the (near) bottom of the tree with the path to that desired object at the near bottom stored so I can store the whole object with all the data I want. Then after I do that I want to remove that object from the greater object  so that I don't ever find it again and repeat the process for as many objects that might be in the greater object until there is nothing left, at which point I am done with this stage.

The problem right now is that I cannot figure out how to remove that object from the greater object so it keeps finding the same one. I have tried setting it to null and the delete keyword. As far as I can tell the when I enact either of those on the "obj" in my "r.removeLowest" method it just applies the change to the obj variable and not to what it is referencing (the object in the tree/greater object).

Any help would be greatly appreciated I'll be up most of the night and checking this routinely.

Test object below:

```
//test object
var sample = {"Ocean Event":
                {"2001":
                    {"Pacific":
                        [{"start":10,"end":30,"magnitude":7},{"start":31,"end":39,"magnitude":9},{"start":40,"end":60,"magnitude":5},{"start":80,"end":90,"magnitude":3},],
                        "Atlantic":
                            [{"start":10,"end":30,"magnitude":3},{"start":40,"end":60,"magnitude":7},{"start":70,"end":90,"magnitude":3}],
                        "Indian":
                            [{"start":0,"end":30,"magnitude":7},{"start":35,"end":60,"magnitude":5},{"start":650,"end":90,"magnitude":3}]
                    },
                    "2002":{"Pacific":
                        [{"start":10,"end":30,"magnitude":7},{"start":40,"end":60,"magnitude":5},{"start":80,"end":90,"magnitude":3}],
                        "Atlantic":
                            [{"start":10,"end":60,"magnitude":3},{"start":40,"end":60,"magnitude":7},{"start":70,"end":90,"magnitude":3}],
                        "Indian":
                            [{"start":0,"end":30,"magnitude":7},{"start":35,"end":60,"magnitude":5},{"start":65,"end":90,"magnitude":3}]
                    },
                    "2003":{"Pacific":
                        [{"start":5,"end":30,"magnitude":7},{"start":40,"end":70,"magnitude":5},{"start":80,"end":90,"magnitude":3}],
                        "Atlantic":
                            [{"start":5,"end":30,"magnitude":3},{"start":40,"end":45,"magnitude":7},{"start":70,"end":90,"magnitude":3}],
                        "Indian":
                            [{"start":10,"end":30,"magnitude":7},{"start":35,"end":60,"magnitude":5},{"start":65,"end":90,"magnitude":3}]
                    }
                },
                "Crime Data":
                    {"2001":
                        {"New York":
                            [{"start":10,"end":30,"magnitude":7},{"start":40,"end":60,"magnitude":5},{"start":80,"end":90,"magnitude":3}],
                            "Atlanta":
                                [{"start":10,"end":60,"magnitude":3},{"start":40,"end":60,"magnitude":7},{"start":70,"end":90,"magnitude":3}],
                            "Bangor":
                                [{"start":0,"end":30,"magnitude":7},{"start":35,"end":60,"magnitude":5},{"start":65,"end":90,"magnitude":3}]
                        },
                        "2002":{"New York":
                            [{"start":10,"end":30,"magnitude":7},{"start":40,"end":60,"magnitude":5},{"start":80,"end":90,"magnitude":3}],
                            "Atlanta":
                                [{"start":10,"end":30,"magnitude":3},{"start":40,"end":60,"magnitude":7},{"start":70,"end":90,"magnitude":3}],
                            "Bangor":
                                [{"start":0,"end":30,"magnitude":7},{"start":35,"end":60,"magnitude":5},{"start":65,"end":90,"magnitude":3}]
                        },
                        "2003":{"New York":
                            [{"start":5,"end":30,"magnitude":7},{"start":40,"end":70,"magnitude":5},{"start":80,"end":90,"magnitude":3}, {"start":91,"end":95,"magnitude":8}],
                            "Atlanta":
                                [{"start":5,"end":30,"magnitude":3},{"start":40,"end":45,"magnitude":7},{"start":70,"end":90,"magnitude":3}],
                            "Bangor":
                                [{"start":10,"end":30,"magnitude":7},{"start":35,"end":60,"magnitude":5},{"start":65,"end":90,"magnitude":3}]
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Script below:

```
var clone = $.extend(true, {}, sample);

//class
function reduceObjectToComponents (obj) {
var r = this
r.keys = []
r.wholeObjects = []
r.root  = $.extend(true, {}, obj)

r.dig = function (node) {
    if(typeof node === 'object'){
        if(Object.keys(node).length>0 && typeof node.start === 'undefined' && node!=null){
            r.keys.push(Object.keys(node)[0])
            r.dig(r.getLatest())
        } else {
            r.storeWhole(node, r.keys)
        }
    }
}

r.storeWhole = function (dataObj, path) {
    var wholeObject = {}
    wholeObject.dimension1 = path[0];
    wholeObject.dimension2 = path[1];
    wholeObject.dimension3 = path[2];
    wholeObject.datum = dataObj;
    console.log(wholeObject)
    r.wholeObjects.push(wholeObject)
    r.removeLowest()
    console.log(r.root)
    console.log(r.keys)
    r.keys = []
    r.dig(r.root)
}

r.removeLowest = function () {
    var obj = r.root
    for (var i = 0; i < r.keys.length; i++) {
        obj = obj[r.keys[i]]
    }
    console.log(obj)
    obj = null
    console.log(obj)
}

r.getLatest = function () {
    var obj = r.root
    for (var i = 0; i < r.keys.length; i++) {
        obj = obj[r.keys[i]]
    }
    return obj
}

r.dig(obj)
}
var t = new reduceObjectToComponents(clone)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an infinite loop because you keep calling `r.dig(r.root)` in `storeWhole`.
I simplified your code a bit, and it seems to traverse your structure correctly (and you don't need to delete anything):

```
r.dig = function (node) {
    if(typeof node === 'object'){
        if(Object.keys(node).length>0 && typeof node.start === 'undefined' && node!=null){
            for(key in node){
                r.keys.push(key);
                r.dig(node[key]);
                r.keys.pop();
            }
        } else {
            r.storeWhole(node, r.keys)
        }
    }
}

r.storeWhole = function (dataObj, path) {
    var wholeObject = {}
    wholeObject.dimension1 = path[0];
    wholeObject.dimension2 = path[1];
    wholeObject.dimension3 = path[2];
    wholeObject.datum = dataObj;
    r.wholeObjects.push(wholeObject)
    console.log(r.keys)
}
```